# Linked List how to know if two identical nodes are different, i.e. different nodes saved in different parts of memory or a reference to the same node

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Ive recently started learning about linked lists and I have a confusion. For the implementation, Im going forward with the Linked list and node implementation used in [linked list problems in leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/description/).

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None
```

Here, Ive solved  [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/description/) by referring to its [existing solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIdigk956u0).

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        # creating a dummy node for storing the answers
        dummy = ListNode()
        tail = dummy
        t2 = tail
        print('PREV')
        print(dummy, tail, t2)
        print('------------------')
        while list1 and list2: # keep looping till one of the lists ends
            # if list1 is less than list2
            if list1.val<list2.val:
                # we add the list1 value to the tail and update the list1 to the next value
                tail.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next
                print('if', tail, '||' ,dummy)
            else:
                # if it is the other way round or they contain the same values, we are storing the list2 node as next and updating
                tail.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next
                print('else', tail, '||', dummy)
            # updating the tail
            tail = tail.next
            print("UPDATED TAIL:", tail)
            print(dummy)
            print('###########')

        # now, if there are mode nodes in one of the two lists
        if list1:
            tail.next = list1
        elif list2:
            tail.next = list2
        print('------------------------')
        print(list1, list2)
        print(tail)
        print(dummy)
        print(t2)
        # returning
        return dummy.next
```

Ideally, the solution does not make use of t2 anywhere, I just created it for the same of my understanding. The output log for this code is given below:

```
PREV
ListNode{val: 0, next: None} ListNode{val: 0, next: None} ListNode{val: 0, next: None}
------------------
else ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}} || ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}
UPDATED TAIL: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}
###########
if ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}} || ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}
UPDATED TAIL: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}
###########
if ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}} || ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}
UPDATED TAIL: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}
ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}
###########
else ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}} || ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}}
UPDATED TAIL: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}
ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}}
###########
else ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}} || ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}}
UPDATED TAIL: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}
ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}}
###########
------------------------
After loop
ListNode{val: 4, next: None} None
ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}
ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}}}
ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}}}
```

When I look at this, I can see and understand what exatly is happening in each iteration. I can see that the lists dummy and tail are being simultaneoulsy updated in each iteration. To be specific,  we are updating the tail and it's next part and that consequently updates the dummy's latest head's next pointer.
What im confused about is this, *Why is this hapenning? Arent these two lists different, why does updating the next of one update the other simultaneously?*
I would like to understand what exactly is going on on a lower level in the memory when we do this operation?

Thanks

Comment: By just reading your title, you can check for identity (`is`) rather than equality `==`.

Comment: only reference is updated rest thing remain same there